# What is the best way to parameterize a Maven script to switch between Spring configurations?

Tags: spring, maven

What is the best way to parameterize a Maven script to switch between Spring configurations?

I have Maven building a WAR file for a web app.  I have alternative spring configurations  - one for integration testing with mock objects, one for live production use with real objects.

Ideally, I would like to have one Maven build script that can build either WAR file.  At present, I just hack the spring config file before building, commenting in and out the mocks and real objects.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you use the [build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

For each profile, you will define a specific Spring configuration:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>integration</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <!-- Specific information for this profile goes here... -->
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>production</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <!-- Specific information for this profile goes here... -->
        </profile>
...
```

You will then activate one profile or the other by setting the parameter **env** : `-Denv=integration` for the first profile, `-Denv=production` for the second profile.

In each `profile` block, you can specify any information specific to your environment. You can then specify `properties`, `plugins`, and so on. In your case, you may change the configuration of the resources plugin in order to include the adequate Spring configuration. For example, in *integration* profile, you can specify where Maven will search the Spring configuration file:

```
<profile>
    <id>integration</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>
            <name>env</name>
            <value>integration</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>/path/to/integration/spring/spring.xml</resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```